The number of non-real quadratic algebraic integers with the given norm in the first quadrant and the upper z-axis.
We know that the norm of an algebraic integer is an integer, so I want to go a step further and know how many quadratic algebraic integers there are with a specific norm. Of course, I want to stipulate that it is on the positive half z axis of the complex plane and in the first quadrant.
\begin{gather*}
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
1&2&3&4&5&\cdots\\
\hline
i&1+i&1+i\sqrt{2}&2i&1+2i\\
\frac{1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}&i\sqrt{2}&i\sqrt{3}&1+i\sqrt{3}&2+i&
\hline\\
&\frac{1+i\sqrt{7}}{2}&\frac{3+i\sqrt{3}}{2}&\frac{3+i\sqrt{7}}{2}&i\sqrt{5}&
\hline\\
&&\frac{1+i\sqrt{11}}{2}&\frac{1+i\sqrt{15}}{2}&\frac{3+i\sqrt{11}}{2}&
\hline\\
&&&&\frac{1+i\sqrt{19}}{2}&
\hline\\
\end{array}
\end{gather*}
I used numerical tests and found that the formula $a_{n}=1 + \lfloor\sqrt{4n-3}\rfloor$ is satisfied, but I can't prove it.
\begin{gather*}
\textbf{Nonexample:}\\\operatorname{Norm}\left(\frac{1+i\sqrt{17}}{3}\right)=2\\
\color{red}{3}\left(\frac{1+i \sqrt{17}}{3}\right)^2-2\cdot\frac{1+i \sqrt{17}}{3}+6=0
\end{gather*}
The non-example describes a quadratic algebraic number with integer norm, but not an algebraic integer.
